# Stripe Standard account oauth set india as country instead of US

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

Hi recently stripe's account API returning country IN instead of US. earlier same thing was returning US.

environment : test

i am using Stripe connect standard accounts to connect merchants on my platform. and issue is when merchant connects with 
 [https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=read_write&client_id={clientId}](https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&scope=read_write&client_id=%7BclientId%7D) 
when i get details of returned account using
Account.retrieve(accountId, requestOptions)
it returns country IN instead of US

can someone help me to resolve this issue as i said earlier it was returning US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the country that the account will be created in by adding e.g. `&stripe_user[country]=US` to the OAuth URL:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize

Comment: can you please let me know what is the reason behind this, because earlier week ago it was taking US as by default

Comment: I think that's something you'd have to ask to Stripe directly, nobody on StackOverflow is likely to know

Comment: already generate ticket 2 weeks ago. but there is no response that's why asked in stackoverflow